# Как можно изменить/сократить/украсить код?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

**Учусь языку python, дошел до темы списки. Решил сделать простенький электронный журнал. Хочу узнать как можно бы было еще лучше написать данную программу. Спасибо заранее за *FeedBack*.**

```
lis = []
i = int(input("Введите кол-во участников в классе: "))
k = 1
n = 0
while n < i:
    print (k,"участник")
    name = str(input("Имя участника: "))
    lis.append (name)
    surname = str(input("Фамилия участника: "))
    lis.append (surname)
    age = int(input("Возраст участника: "))
    lis.append (age)
    k = k + 1
    n = n + 1
sog = int(input("Желаете ли вы проверить данные? (1 - Да, 0 - Нет) "))
if sog == 1:
    vvod = str(input("Введите фамилию участника: "))
    vvod2 = lis.index(vvod)
    print ("Данные внесены в систему следующим образом: ",lis[vvod2-1], lis[vvod2], lis[vvod2+1],"лет")

else:
    print("Прощайте!")
    exit
```

Comment: Можете хранить список списков. Т.е. список, элементами которого будут списки, идентифицирующие каждого участника. Например: `[ [Петя, Петров, 86], [Иван, Иванов, 3], ...]`.

Comment: А можно хранить список словарей :) `[ { "name" : "Петя", "surname" : "Петров", "age" : 86}, ... ]`, потом информацию о каждом участнике можно будет вытянуть, например, так: `lis[i]["name"]`

Comment: Переменная `k` не нужна. Замените её на `n+1`. + доавить бы проверки различного рода и структурировать данные в список словарей, как привели пример выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### По хранению данных

1. Вы можете использовать список списков, чтобы не искать информацию о каждом участнике, как `lis[i-1]`, `lis[i]`, `lis[i+1]`. В случае списка списков, Вы сможете получать информацию так: `lis[i][0] # Имя`, `lis[i][1] # Фамилия`, `lis[i][2] # Возраст`.
   В Вашем коде это будет выглядеть так:

```py
name = str(input("Имя участника: "))
surname = str(input("Фамилия участника: "))
age = int(input("Возраст участника: "))
lis.append([name, surname, age])
```

2. Также можно использовать список словарей, чтобы обращаться к полям участников более явно:

```py
lis.append({ "name" : name, "surname" : name, "age" : age })
```

Затем к полям i-го участника Вы сможете обращаться, например, так:

```py
lis[i]["surname"]
```

#### По коду

1. Зачем вам переменная `k`? Только чтобы выводить `k участник`, начиная с 1? В таком случае используйте `n+1` вместо `k`, как Вам уже подсказали в комментариях.
2. Списки в Python не имеют фиксированную длину :) Добавлять участников можно в цикле `while True:`, пока пользователь не впишет какое-нибудь служебное слово (например, `"quit"`)

```py
while True:
    name = input("Имя участника (quit - выход): ")
    if name == "quit":
        break
    #...
```

3. Если Вы всё же хотите использовать `while n < i:`, то лучше освободите переменную `n` и воспользуйтесь циклом `for n in range(i):`
4. `sog = int(input("Желаете ли вы проверить данные? (1 - Да, 0 - Нет) "))` А если пользователь введёт не 0 или не 1? :) Можно было бы добавить какую-нибудь проверку :)

```py
while True:
    try: # try except для того, чтобы обработать случай, если пользователь напишет не цифру (например, "y")
        sog = int(input("Желаете ли вы проверить данные? (1 - Да, 0 - Нет) "))
        if sog == 0 or sog == 1:
            break
        else:
            continue
    except:
        continue
```

5. Данные можно проверить только 1 раз и только для одного участника? Может, тоже стоит обернуть в `while True:`, пока пользователь не введёт **0**?

```py
while sog == 1:
    # Выполняем проверку
    # ...
    while True:
        try: # try except для того, чтобы обработать случай, если пользователь напишет не цифру (например, "y")
            sog = int(input("Желаете ли вы проверить данные? (1 - Да, 0 - Нет) "))
            if sog == 0 or sog == 1:
                break
            else:
                continue
        except:
            continue
```

(Согласен, слишком много `while True:`, но в Python отсутствует цикл `do {} while ()`, поэтому выкручиваются так :))

6. `vvod = str(input("Введите фамилию участника: "))` А если будет введена фамилия, которой нет в списке участников? Думаю, лучше проверять перебором

```py
# Для случая, когда у нас список словарей
vvod = str(input("Введите фамилию участника: "))
for member in lis:
    if member["surname"] == vvod:
        # Что-то делаем
        break
else:
    # Делаем что-то, если участника не нашли
```

Тут ещё можно дополнять и дополнять, но я устал...) Вообще, внешний вид кода (*сократить/украсить*) вещь довольно субъективная, так что тут на вкус и цвет. А про явные недочёты, типа ненужной переменной, плохого цикла и проверок на ввод пользователя я написал.

Comment: Спасибо, учту ваш комментарий и перепишу программу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, как вариант.

```
def info():
  n = 0
  lis = []
  i = int(input("Введите кол-во участников в классе: "))

  while n < i:
      dct = {}
      print (n+1,"участник")
      name = str(input("Имя участника: "))
      if name.isalpha():
        dct['name'] = name
      else:
        print('Вы ввели некорректные данные')
        continue
      surname = str(input("Фамилия участника: "))
      if surname.isalpha():
        dct['surname'] = surname
      else:
        print('Вы ввели некорректные данные')
        continue
      age = input("Возраст участника: ")
      if age.isdigit():
        dct['age'] = age
      else:
        print('Вы ввели некорректные данные')
        continue
      lis.append(dct)
      n = n + 1

  sog = int(input("Желаете ли вы проверить данные? (1 - Да, 0 - Нет) "))
  if sog == 1:
      vvod = str(input("Введите фамилию участника: "))
      for i in lis:
        if vvod == list(i.values())[1]:
          res = "Данные внесены в систему следующим образом: " + i['name'] + ' ' + i['surname'] + ' ' + i['age'] + ' ' +  "лет"
          break
  else:
      res = "Прощайте!"

  return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(info())
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенный вариант!